# How to check characters alternatively and replace it with Y if it is X?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string, something like this:

```
$str ="it is a test string.";

 // for more clarification

 i t   i s   a   t e  s  t     s  t  r  i  n  g  .
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Now I need to **check** all characters that are multiples of 4 *(plus first character)*. like these:

```
1  => i
4  => i
8  => [space]
12 => t
16 => r
20 => .
```

Now, I need to **compare** them with `Y` *(`Y` is a variable (symbol), for example `Y = 'r'` in here)*. So I want to replace `Y` with `X` (`X` is a variable (symbol) too, for example `X = 'm'` in here).

So, I want this **output:**

```
it is a test stming.
```

---

Here is my **solution**: I can do that using some PHP function:

- `strlen($str)`: to count the number of characters *(named `$sum`)*
- `$sum / 4`: To find characters that are multiples of 4
- `substr($str, 4,1)`: to select specific character *(named `$char`)*  *{the **problem** is here}*
- `if ($char == 'r') {}`: to compare
- `str_replace('r','m',$char)`: to replace

And then combining all `$char` to each other.

---

But my solution has two **problem**:

1. `substr()` does not count `[space]` character *(As I mentioned above)*
2. combining characters is complicated a bit. *(It needs to some waste processing)*

Well, is there any solution? I like to do that using REGEX, Is it possible?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "`substr()` does not count `[space]`"? I don't understand this one.

Comment: `$chars = explode('', $string);` will give you an array containing all characters. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Passerby `echo substr($str, 4, 1)`=> output: `s`. `s` is the fifth character. So `substr()` does not count [space]

Comment: @Shafizadeh No......string and array indexes count from 0, not 1.

Comment: @Passerby Oh, yeah seems you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an alternative using **[preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)**

```php
$y = 'r';
$y = preg_quote($y, '/');
$x = 'M';
$x = preg_quote($x, '/');
$subject = 'rrrrrr rrrrr rrrrrr rrrr rrrr.';

$regex = "/\\G(?:^|(?(?<!^.).)..(?:.{4})*?)\\K$y/s";

$result = preg_replace($regex, $x, $subject);

echo $result;
// => MrrMrr MrrrM rrMrrr rrrM rrMr.
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/AKEGco)</kbd>

---

Regex:

```
\G(?:^|(?(?<!^.).)..(?:.{4})*?)\Km
```

- `\G` is an assertion to the end of last match (or start of string)
- `(?:^|(?(?<!^.).)..(?:.{4})*?)` matches:

  - `^` start of string, to check at position 1
  - `(?(?<!^.).)` is an if clause that yields:

    1. `..(?:.{4})*?)` 2 chars + a multiple of 4 if it has just replaced at position 1
    2. `...(?:.{4})*?)` 3 chars + a multiple of 4 for successive matches
- `\K` resets the text matched to avoid using backreferences

---

I must say though, regex is an overkill for this task. This code is counterintuitive and a typical regex that proves difficult to understand/debug/maintain.

---

**EDIT**. There was a later discussion about performance vs. code readability, so I did a benchmark to compare:

1. RegEx with a callback ([@bobblebubble's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33731267/5290909)).
2. RegEx with 2 replacements in an array ([@bobblebubble's suggestion in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730320/how-to-check-characters-alternatively-and-replace-it-with-y-if-it-is-x/33731267#comment55245698_33731267)).
3. No RegEx with `substr_replace` ([@Passerby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33730641/5290909)).
4. Pure RegEx (this answer).

Result:

```
Code #1(with_callback):   0.548 secs/50k loops
Code #2(regex_array):     0.158 secs/50k loops
Code #3(no_regex):        0.120 secs/50k loops
Code #4(pure_regex):      0.118 secs/50k loops
```

<kbd>[Benchmark in ideone.com](http://ideone.com/5ZFCFe)</kbd>

Comment: Why downvote? it does not work correctly? I tested it and I think it is work as well ...

Comment: The `(?:.{4})*?` part is entirely redundant, from what I can see.

Comment: @salathe I don't think so. You see, the pattern is anchored to `\G`, and it needs to consume 4x chars. If there's something I'm missing, can you clarify?

Comment: Neat idea, but more difficult to understand! upvote for single regex without callback.

Comment: @Mariano I see it now, no worries.

Comment: Also, "I must say though, regex is an overkill for this task." I wouldn't say *overkill*, but it's going to be a maintenance nightmare: I'm sure @Shafizadeh doesn't want to come back to SO to get someone to explain what on earth the regex is doing. :-)

Comment: It's fun to play with regexes @salathe :p

Comment: @bobblebubble Indeed. I wrote down the logic and I ended up with everything upside-down. It's not following a "natural logic", to improve efficiency. For example, I started with `((.{4})*?.{3})` and ended with `.{3}` before `(.{4})*?`.

Comment: @salathe I agree, it's a typical regex that proves difficult to maintain. But it was clearly stated by OP he wanted this kind of solution. Hopefully it serves to encourage a deeper understanding of regex.

Comment: Yes I couldn't be online to attend it at that time and moreover my answer wasn't correct so it is good that you posted your working solution.

Answer (score 9):

Could just use a [simple regex](https://regex101.com/r/dA4wS2/1) with [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) (add `u` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) if utf-8, `s` for `.` to match newline).

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(['/^./', '/.{3}\K./'], function ($m) {
  return $m[0] == "r" ? "m" : $m[0];
}, $str); echo $str;
```

[See this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##NY1BC4IwAEbv@xUfQ1BBZtAtE69BF@9mssbSkc6xzZP425cVHd97h2cGE8K5qi81IZHzFiVVHsqBw0vnsSule0aLf4axsu@sNCMXshN8HB9cvJImzu8sjzPEOVuP2@26Q5vhuWjh1ayRRFOKlQBW@sVqRFNzaFGWoJaiAp0oTj9ZkC3D55XuTymG@QtFCG8) > `it is a test stming.`

- 1st pattern: `^.` any first character
- 2nd pattern: `\K` resets after `.{3}` any three characters, only want to check the fourth `.`

For use with anonymous function PHP >= 5.3 is required. [Here is the workaround (demo)](https://tio.run/##LY27CoMwAEX3fMUlCCoULXSrDa6FLu7WSgyphmoMMU7it6fpYzwH7rlmMN5fyupaERItzoJR5aAWcDi5OASldJ/RgpDnqoVTs4bokmhKscFKt1qNaKqPDRgDtRQl6ERx/skC@78KY2XfWmlGLmQr@Dh2XLySOs4fWR4fEOfZdtrvtwBNINEF91mm4ViKYf5C4f0b).

---

*Update:* [@Mariano demonstrated in his very nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33732565/5527985) that it is **even with a single regex** replacement possible. Thank you for the benchmark that reveals a rather bad performance for the `preg_replace_callback` solution. A more efficient [variant without callback](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLS6W4pEjBVimzRCGzWCFRoSS1uEQBKJSZl66nZA2TVigoSk2PL0otyElMTtWIVtePK9JX11FQ19ewt9LT04uOK4rV1AIyYryB4rFAiVygLEirJtCI1OSMfDDH@v9/AA) (but still two patterns).

```
$str = preg_replace(['/^r/', '/(?:...[^r])*...\Kr/'], 'm', $str);
```

I also included [@revo's answer from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47371771/5527985) in [Mariano's benchmark and ran it on tio.run](https://tio.run/##lVRdb9owFH0mv@KWZYrNRwKle1hDGq1TtU19qdS98aWQmhI1H8gJ6yoKf53dayeQbVXXGQnZ19fn3HOPndVytd8P/ZuvN4axWKdhEWUprNZSzKS4Fz8Zh43RMKXI13EBHqwwijurOAgFs5zxF@afT5@Zz/zhydTm@LMxYm/Otrzl8/G1dHKrA1ZCf1EBUQ4BFCIvIC9klN7bFneN7ZH4MSqWszCI43kQPrzGfUwaWc7UdgjfsTeD7fgaF5MOHCCZmRAOVEOKYi1TMJNRbwKeB5a0wKcK4VwH3Sp3@7aa06zWKjpnYh54Lx91UVAsUlSDEZwwSka8RrRQU@T3PCyJQ7nCTKwNExaZZGbkDVwwoyFh0KTtnXGjAVCdNqNKkwrrWnRUw9TqVkXPAimDp1ddpgZL3WBlN3V5NJUT3mrrhpPHk/8wuUZ8@g/m3fiT3BHsTlMx/0I@26x1e/3thjP/hPPdW6jNOYU8@FgN1zAfM6liPVdvz9J1gstu3z1Wmq@EuJsRHjPD7E50wIyzbJVj3oceDV39XKA5AoNJFMqsiBLBCrkWXLsGZFsPSt/UcWVdWx1WJhE2o/QtogWLQsgXwcw7EQdPuKVzuiUx7lSXWiWQYjAcB7rlwJWZBomgukfWb2@M@lbz44/lKa2r@03z44fBwndyaEZfNQMfjkH1BOESNWvCINfqdHcvwFxwY1NTUu/womqvfg@IobOGoAxS7WpUVlZSy0jp3oFL97IGgtTK8RKlcv8Ag9kiXGZgfUYEeGeBDexYeRv6HCPNUtbosDPh5@OiiVs4nws5Q/1JUJSkHRioU5CLMHcoS@tz@lcDij@AWo7TJlmm6JuXV7ff8UNU0lTSJjB/gr9pWL@rewPOQV6L3OhATzG/h@wHXiatNgxy0XT3@18) (100k loops). With newer PHP and PCRE2 the numbers seem to have changed slightly, "no regex" leads at tio.run.

---

In *.NET* or modern browser *JS regex* it also [could be done like this](https://regex101.com/r/NCZNUa/1) by a variable length lookbehind.

Comment: @Shafizadeh Welcome! Need PHP >= 5.3 for use of anonymous function.

Comment: @bobblebubble Ah, So here is my problem, PHP < 5.3, I told to myself several times: why this answer works on demo but is does not work on my local system ...! anyway thanks again.

Comment: @Shafizadeh See updated answer, this would also check first chr.

Comment: Very good, Now it works completely correct, I will mark it as my answer if @anubhava refuses to edit his answer.

Comment: This is good answer +1. @Shafizadeh: Sorry I had to rush to a meeting. After coming back I noticed good new answers so deleted mine as it needed correction.

Comment: @anubhava Ah I see. Just one thing: as you said, this answer is good, yes I know, but what is your opinion about Mariano's answer? it even has not a condition, it is pure regex ...! So, which one?

Comment: This solution is easier to understand & maintain but yes it is not pure regex solution. Given a choice I would keep understandable solution in my code.

Comment: @Shafizadeh I'd also choose code you, or anyone editing your code, could easily understand/debug/maintain. The only drawback of a callback is performance. Benchmark: http://ideone.com/5ZFCFe

Comment: @Mariano Thank you for the interesting benchmark! Played a bit and probably [something like this](https://eval.in/469582) (similar to your no_regex sample) coudn't be made much faster anymore. Maybe a little? I'm impressed by the performance of your pure regex!

Comment: @Mariano What about a [mix like this](https://eval.in/469700) `$str = preg_replace(['/^r/', '/(?:...[^r])*...\Kr/'], 'm', $str);` partly understandable and of better performance than callback :p Well, I think your regex pattern is brilliant... hats off

Comment: @bobblebubble You know what is brilliant? earning almost 1K rep in 12 days..! Bravo ..

Comment: @Shafizadeh Oh, thank you! Actually don't care much about that, just love those regex riddles popping up here so frequently.

Comment: btw, may I have your Skype account?

Comment: @bobblebubble I added your suggestion to the [benchmark](http://ideone.com/5ZFCFe). It's a pretty good balance between readability and performance.

Comment: @Mariano Thanks for all the effort! Love your pure regex solution. Yet unsung, should definetly have higher voting.

Answer (score 6):

If all characters in your string are in single byte, you can use something from [PHP's official language reference](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

```
$str ="it is a test string.";
$y="r";
$x="m";
$len=strlen($str);
if($str[0]==$y)
{
    $str=substr_replace($str,$x,0,1);
}
if($len>=3)
{
    for($i=3;$i<$len;$i+=4)
    {
        if($str[$i]==$y)
        {
            $str=substr_replace($str,$x,$i,1);
        }
    }
}
var_dump($str);
```

[3v4l demo](https://3v4l.org/gdiW8)

Outputs `it is a test stming.`

---

Edit:

As @Don'tPanic points out, String is mutable using `[]` operator, so instead of using

```
$str=substr_replace($str,$x,$i,1);
```

you can just use

```
$str[$i]=$x;
```

Comment: Incidentally, you can also modify the string directly with `$str[$i] = $x` instead of using `substr_replace`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Oops, didn't realized that. Thanks! I'll update this to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$str ="it is a test string.";
$y="r";
$x="m";    

$splite_array = str_split($str);

foreach ($splite_array as $key => $val)
{
    if($key % 4 == 0 && $val == $y)
    {
        $splite_array[$key] = $x;
    }
}

$yout_new_string  = implode($splite_array);
```

Comment: This answer has a good algorithm, but honestly does not work for me, why it has  earned 4 upvote?! Can anybody please give me a demo of this solution?

Comment: Try this code on a single page , then u can realize it working fine and I think u can detect your error

Comment: @Shafizadeh [See this demo](https://eval.in/469422), I also gave upvote because idea is neat.

Comment: You may want to change this `$splite_array[$key] = $x;` to this `$str[$key] = $x;` and avoid `implode` function.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code could help you on your way:

```
// Define variables
$string = "it is a test string.";
$y = 'r';
$x = 'm';

// Convert string to array
$chars = explode('', $string);

// Loop through all characters
foreach ($chars as $key => $char) {
    // Array keys start at 0, so we add 1
    $keyCount = $key+1;

    // Check if deviding the key by 4 doesn't have rest value
    // This means it is devisable by 4
    if ($keyCount % 4 == 0 && $value == $y) {
        $chars[$key] = $x;
    }
}

// Convert back to string
$string = implode($chars);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one other way to do this using [string access and modification by character](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr). (Consequently, it is only useful for single-byte encoded strings.)

```
// First character handled outside the loop because its index doesn't match the pattern
if ($str[0] == $y) $str[0] = $x;

// access every fourth character
for ($i=3; isset($str[$i]) ; $i+=4) {
    // change it if it needs to be changed
    if ($str[$i] == $y) $str[$i] = $x;
}
```

This modifies the original string rather than creating a new string, so if that shouldn't happen, it should be used on a copy.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, puting aside `\G` anchor, I'd go with `(*SKIP)(*F)` method:

```
$str = "it is a test string.";
echo preg_replace(['~\Ar~', '~.{3}\K(?>r|.(*SKIP)(?!))~'], 'm', $str);
```

Short and clean.

[**PHP live demo**](https://3v4l.org/FuYp1)